# Creating a bound on a value within the program

Tags: c++, variables

I am currently writing a program that will take in a lot of user input and as a result will change certain variables.

What I am trying to accomplish is to set a bound for these values, such as the variable "age" of the object cannot exceed 50 and is greater than or equal to 0. 
range: [0, 50]

What would be the best way to the best way to set a maximum for the value?
For example:
age = 46
age = age + 10 // new value of age would be 50 as that is the maximum.

I know I could implement this with if statements within the scope of the operations

```
if (age > 50) {age = 50;}
else if (age < 0) {age = 0;}
```

following the operation to change the value.

I am going to be dealing with many different variables within the structure such as age, hunger, happiness, etc. and would rather not have to repeat the if statements for each one.

Is there a way I can define bounds on the variables previously and if it ever leaves the bounds it throws an error or returns a variable?

If it helps my current implementation of the changing of values is:
with an enum 'Operation' defining the operations seen below.

```
int modifyHunger(Operation operation, int value)
{
    switch(operation)
    {
        case INCREMENT:
            myHunger = myHunger + value;
            break;
        case DECREMENT:
            myHunger = myHunger - value;
            break;
        case REINIT:
            myHunger = 0;
            break;
        case INIT:
            myHunger = value;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return myHunger;
}
```

Comment: Maybe make a `BoundedInterval` class? Basically the constructor would take the lower and upper bounds for that object. Then you can overload the mathematical operators `+`, `-`, etc, to take care of the bounding logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle this question, but my personal choice is using min and max over direct conditionals.  So for example we can implement a function to clamp values like this:

```
template <typename T> 
T clamp(const T &value, const T &lower, const T &upper) 
{ 
    return max(lower, min(value, upper)); 
}
```

The advantage to this method is that it is generalized for any type which can be used with min and max.

Edit:
Just to expand on the idea further you can also make a class which overloads basic math operators and implicitly calls clamp.  Which can be even more elegant, and in that case probably won't need a template.
It's up to you to expand this into something comfortable for your taste and use case.